# Is the submit button the only way to execute a php file?

Tags: php, html

Suppose you wished to create a HTML/php script which produced a webpage containing 2 buttons which, when clicked, told you which button had been clicked. The only way of doing this using php that I know of, is to create the index file

```
<? include('buttons.php'); ?>

<? include('clicked.php'); ?>
```

Where buttons.php is saved in the same directory and contains

```
<form method="post">

<input type="submit" name="button1" value="button1">
<input type="submit" name="button2" value="button2">

</form>
```

And the php script clicked.php contains

```
<?php



if($_POST['button1']){
echo "You have clicked button1";

}



elseif($_POST['button2']){
echo "You have clicked button2";

}

?>
```

This method works, but I suspect that it's not the best way of using php to get this result.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You are already doing the right thing

Comment: You could also use a link with a param, ie. `<a href="index.php?action=button2" />...</a>` and check with `if(isset($_GET['action'])){ if($_GET['action'] == 'button1') {} elseif($_GET['action'] == 'button2'){}`

Comment: Your question rather be, is there any other way of doing it, because this seems to be the normal way of calling a php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a server-side solution to executing PHP file however, you can approach this using client-side code and a generic handler for real-time executing and page-loading.

jQuery is free, world-wide used framework for JavaScript extensions and is easy to use.

```
$("#btn-one").click(function() {
    $.get("clicked.php", { button: 1})
    .done(function (data) {
        body.innerHTML = data;
    });
});
```

Your PHP (clicked.php) would look like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['button'])):
    switch($_GET['button'])
    {
        case 1:
            echo "You pressed button 1";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "You pressed button 2";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
endif;
```

And finally, your HTML would look like this!

```
<button type="button" id="btn-one">Button 1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own wrapper

```
class Input
{
    public static function fetch($key, $rules=[])
    {
        // ctype_alnum is used to check if the $key is alphanumeric
        if (ctype_alnum($key) && isset($_POST[$key])) {
            return $_POST[$key];
        }
        return false; // or ''
    }
}
// practical use
// If string
$option = (string) Input::fetch('option');
```

Change the name to button[]

Then use the switch function.

you could use the rules argument to add validation rules and check for expected response types.